# Room library won't accept byte array

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, android-room

I am using Room library for Android to make a database. It has one simple table with id, date, title, text, address and image.
The problem appears when I try to insert byte array into the table (I am using test entries through for loop for test). I am converting the image to `byte[]`. It works ok when I put simple string instead of image.

Here is the error:

```
Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 6 columns.

FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.database.test.app, PID: 18552
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:524)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
at com.database.test.app.EntryDao_Impl.getAllEntries(EntryDao_Impl.java:183)
at com.database.test.app.MainActivity$CreateAndExportBase.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:191)
at com.database.test.app.MainActivity$CreateAndExportBase.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:151)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Why you try to save binary file into database?

Comment: I have to insert an image into the db.

Comment: You should not use database for storing files. Put them into application data dir and save path in database.

Comment: I have to insert them into db because I am exporting db as a backup file. There will be many images.

Comment: Create zip with images and database file. Read (for example) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: Problem is that I have limited storage size for backup
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Comment: If your images cached from web, then don't backup it. If images are user-generated content - you may backup it to backend/storage.  
User data backup is not for storing images.

Comment: So it is not available to convert user-generated images to byte[], insert them into DB and backup the DB? Only way is to backup them to some storage?

Comment: You may convert byte[] to string (for example via base64), but your database file size will be more than size of all images. And it may be greater than allowed to backup

Comment: cursor window has a system dependent limit (usually 2mb) and your images might be going over that limit.

Comment: did you find the solution?   @filipst

Comment: @RushDroid unfortunately no, I didn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How insert image in room persistence library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337519/how-insert-image-in-room-persistence-library)

Answer (score 11):

To store image file into db you need to declare your table field with "BLOB" datatype.
But Room will consider "byte[]" as "String" and thats y  you are not able to store image.

Following will do the trick.

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "your columnname",typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
private byte[] yourfield;
```

Comment: @RushDroid setting typeAffinity to Blob works for me and others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337519/how-insert-image-in-room-persistence-library/46356934#46356934.
Can you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: can you please share your code if you don't mind.unfortunately its not working for me @Pinakin

Comment: See the answer posted in the link contains example code for byte declaration.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337519/how-insert-image-in-room-persistence-library/46356934#46356934

Comment: Then share your example implementation so, I can debug and let you know what is wrong. or share error you are getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160900/discussion-between-rushdroid-and-pinakin).

Comment: How bytearray converted to blob? How we can re-convert this blob data to bytearray in other platforms?